# R: Replace last 3 zeroes with K in a column

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to replace last 3 000 with K in a column in the dataframe

eg:

```
data <- data.frame(abc = c(1000, 100000, 450000))

abc <- 1000
then abc <- 1K

if 
abc <- 100000
then abc <- 100K
```

gsub or regex replaces the first 3 zeroes

I tried this:

```
lapply(data$abc, gsub, pattern = "000", replacement = "K", fixed = TRUE)
```

Also, how can I make it work on an interval like :

```
data <- data.frame(abc = c("150000-250000", "100000-150000", "250000K+"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to use `%/%` with 1000 and paste the "K"

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
   mutate(abc = str_c(abc %/% 1000, "K"))
```

---

Or using `sub`, match the 3 zeros at the end (`$`) of the string and replace with `"K"`

```
options(scipen = 999)
sub("0{3}$", "K", data$abc)
#[1] "1K"   "100K" "450K"
```

If we have a different string with interval, then change the pattern to match 3 zeros at either at the end (`$`) or before a `-` and replace with "K"

```
gsub("0{3}(?=-|$)", "K", "150000-250000", perl = TRUE)
#[1] "150K-250K"
```

Comment: 100000 becomes 1e+05

Comment: Also, how can I make it work on an interval like : 150000-250000

Comment: @BruceWayne  The scientific format can be changed with `options` (updated). regardng the second option we need `gsub` and pattern should be slightly changed

Comment: Could you help me with the interval part please?

Comment: @BruceWayne  Updated the post

Comment: @akrun this will mean if you had 1000:2000, then you will need to change the regex, i would rather prefer `0{3}(?!0)` instead

Comment: @Onyambu Sure, I thought the OP had only a single pattern or `gsub("0{3}(?=[:-]|$)", "K", "1000:2000", perl = TRUE)
[1] "1K:2K"`

Comment: @BruceWayne  Please include all your patterns in the question.  This was based on the initial pattern showed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400344/r-fuzzy-merge-two-data-frame can you help with this question too please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight modification of your code. `format` is to turn off the scientific notation. `sapply` makes the output becomes a vector. `000$` means only match those at the end.

```
data <- data.frame(abc = c(1000, 100000, 450000))

data$abc <- format(data$abc, scientific = FALSE)

gsub(pattern = "000$", replacement = "K", data$abc)
# [1] "  1K" "100K" "450K"
```

Comment: `gsub` is  vectorized,  whats the purpose of `sapply here?

Comment: @Onyambu Good point. I was affected by the `lapply` OP used. I have updated my solution now. Thanks.